# CSS3 checkbox and radio disabled state

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some hard time understanding how to add a disabled class to reference an image with this checkbox and radio CSS3 code.

Any suggestion? I tried adding

```
input[type="checkbox"] [type="disabled"] + label:before {
    background: url(".images/radio-check.png") -38px no-repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

The demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/h6JFG/3/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206960/how-to-set-css-for-disabled-checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need

`<input id="c1" type="checkbox" disabled name="cc">`

First item is disabled: http://jsfiddle.net/h6JFG/134/

**Edit**

If you want to target the disabled state, you can do so like this:

```
input[disabled]+label:before{
    background:#000 !important;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/h6JFG/135/

Comment: As ElGavilan showed, this can also be targetted with CSS using 'input[disabled]'

Comment: but how can I add the actual image? I dont see any disabled class on the css

Comment: the first item is normal state. a disabled state is different. I want to add another icon for that , same for radio... do you know what i mean?

Comment: are you asking how to style the disabled state differently than the normal state?

Comment: Correct Jordan. I think I didn't explain myself properly.

Comment: see my edit above.  I've also included a fiddle to cehck out.  The !important part isn't necessary.